# how to fix: mysql exceptions.OperationalError: 1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.1.7' (using password: YES)"

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, mysql-python

Am recording the room temperature using a Raspberry Pi 3.The recorded temperature has to be sent to my system and it should be stored in mysql database.But am unable to access mysql remotely.

I do have granted all the privileges and commented the blind-address

OS : ubuntu 18.04

Thanku for help

```
def main():

        while True:

                temperature = sensor.get_temperature()
                print("The temperature is %s celsius" % temperature)
                time.sleep(1)

                #Code to write the recorded temperature in the MYSQL 
                #database 'templog' and table 'temp-at-interrupt'

                db = MySQLdb.connect(host="192.168.1.6", user="root", 
                passwd="root", db="templog")

                cur = db.cursor()
                print("connected to db")
```

```
The temperature is 30.625 celsius
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp-3.py", line 47, in <module>
    main()
  File "temp-3.py", line 25, in main
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="192.168.1.6", user="root", passwd="root", db="templog")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.1.7' (using password: YES)")
```

Comment: Have you created a user account 'root'@'192.168.1.7' in the database?

Comment: yes i do have created a user account root@192.168.1.1 and have also tried giving local host instead of ip address and created another user for that too.Neither of them worked

Comment: The IP address attached to the account you mention is not the same as the one the client is coming from. Try creating an account 'root'@'192.168.1.%', which probably permits access from anywhere on your local network.